# field element dictionary lookup

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

Apologies in advance for a stupid question. I started with C# 3 days ago. I have a requirement to automate document creation. The documents are created from configuration outputs that I convert into xml, and then into word. So far I've managed to combine the magic of XMLwriter and FieldParser as shown below.

I would now like to add a lookup of sorts. For example, int _librarytype; below would return a number e.g "8" and I would like to print the associated value "TLD". I've read about dictionaries but cant' figure out how or where to apply them to the array member.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    class StorageUnit
    {
        string _storagename;
        int _storageunittype;
        string _hostConnection;
        int _librarytype;
        int _robotnumber;
        int _density;
        int _maxconjobsnumberdrives;
        int _multiplexing;
        int _fragsize;
        string _diskpool;

        public StorageUnit(string storageunitname, int storageunittype, string hostconnection, int librarytype, int robotnumber, int density, int maxconjobsnumberdrives, int multiplexing, int fragsize, string diskpool)
        {
            _storagename = storageunitname;
            _storageunittype = storageunittype;
            _hostConnection = hostconnection;
            _librarytype = librarytype;
            _robotnumber = robotnumber;
            _density = density;
            _maxconjobsnumberdrives = maxconjobsnumberdrives;
            _multiplexing = multiplexing;
            _fragsize = fragsize;
            _diskpool = diskpool;
        }

        public string storageunitname { get { return _storagename; } }
        public int storageunittype { get { return _storageunittype; } }
        public string hostconnection { get { return _hostConnection; } }
        public int librarytype { get { return _librarytype; } }
        public int robotNumber { get { return _robotnumber; } }
        public int density { get { return _density; } }
        public int maxconjobsnumberdrives { get { return _maxconjobsnumberdrives; } }
        public int multiplexing { get { return _multiplexing; } }
        public int fragsize { get { return _fragsize; } }
        public string diskpool { get { return _diskpool; } }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = "\t";
        using (TextFieldParser storageunits = new TextFieldParser("C:\\Input Files\\bpstulist.txt"))
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\Output Files\\StorageUnits.xml",settings))
        {
            storageunits.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            storageunits.Delimiters = new string[] { " " };
            storageunits.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            storageunits.TrimWhiteSpace = true;


            string[] stuprops;
            int stunumber = 0;
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("StorageUnits");
            while (!storageunits.EndOfData)
            {
                stuprops = storageunits.ReadFields();
                writer.WriteStartElement("StorageUnit");
                writer.WriteElementString("StorageUnitName", stuprops[0]);
                writer.WriteElementString("StorageUnitType", stuprops[1].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("HostConnection", stuprops[2]);
                writer.WriteElementString("LibraryType", stuprops[3].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("RobotNumber", stuprops[4].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("Density", stuprops[5].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("MaxConcurrentDrives", stuprops[6].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("Multiplexing", stuprops[10].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("FragmentSize", stuprops[11].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("Diskpool", stuprops[19]);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                stunumber++;
                     writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does "TLD" come from?

Comment: TLD is a tape library type, its known but not used in the configuration output.. In sql i would have a lookup to perform this function. The library type in "C:\\Input Files\\bpstulist.txt" is defined as a number (1,2,3,4,5,6 etc). Each of those refer to a specific library (tape library) type (ASC, TLD, TLH, etc). I know what these are and want to document them somewhere so in that in the output it shows the string instead of just an integer.

Comment: One more thing, I've reversed engineered an example to get to the state above. I dont however understand what the class StorageUnit is providing. I can still get the info out of my file and write it to xml if its not there. Is it redundant?

Comment: It looks like it gives read-only access to the storage unit elements in the XML file. In the code you have presented the class is obviously redundant (delete it & the code compiles - after missing where the missing final close brace goes). As far as the original question is concerned - if there are a relatively small number of library types referred to by sequential integers, as you have described, then I would have used an array of strings rather than a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll take out all the redundant stuff. Can you give me an example to do the lookup? I'm sure I can figure it out with a pertinent example. I've gotten this far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I added

```
Dictionary<int, string> lib_lookup = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                                                            {
                                                                {0, "NONE"},
                                                                {1, "ACS"},
                                                                {2, "TS8"},
                                                                {5, "ODL"},
                                                                {6, "TL8"},
                                                                {7, "TL4"},
                                                                {8, "TLD"},
                                                                {10, "TSD"},
                                                                {11, "TSH"},
                                                                {12, "TLH"},
                                                                {13, "TLM"},
                                                                {17, "LMF"},
                                                             };
```

And then I referred to it later to get the correct value.

```
                        int librarynumber;
                    bool libparsed = Int32.TryParse((stuprops[3]), out librarynumber);
                    string libtypestring = lib_lookup[(librarynumber)];
                    writer.WriteElementString("LibraryType", libtypestring);
```

The string to int to string seems a bit convoluted but I'm still learning.